# Gulp browser-sync proxy

Tags: proxy, gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to setup browser-sync to work via proxy:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        notify: false,
        browser: "chrome",
        proxy:{
            host:"localhost"
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is it seems cannot work with proxy directly, instead request for manually putting in snippet into website.

However, if I try with global browser-sync `browser-sync start --proxy "localhost"`, it works.

How can I get the gulp browser-sync's proxy works? Or, how can I have the global browser-sync to work with gulp? It is important, so that browser-sync can work with my gulp logic and reload browser when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [to the docs](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy) you should be using `target` rather than `host`.

```
proxy: {
    target: "http://yourlocal.dev"
}
```

Or simply

```
proxy: "local.dev"
```

like @niba has in his answer

Answer (score 2):

Your json format with options is wrong. Proxy field doesn't have nested properties. Try this one:

```
browserSync({
        notify: false,
        browser: "chrome",
        proxy: "localhost"
    });
```

Comment: Proxy does have nested properties, check out the docs http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy he needs to use 'target' rather than host however.